# Windows Forms with SQlite Project runs well in Visual-Studio while. But the setup file when installed shows an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'SQLite.NET, Version=0.21.1869.3794, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=c273bd375e695f9c' or one of its dependencies. The system 
cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'SQLite.NET, Version=0.21.1869.3794, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=c273bd375e695f9c'
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs 
e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons 
button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr 
wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value 
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind 
failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value 
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    CodeBase: 
file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsApplication1
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Public/Desktop/WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    CodeBase: 
 file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/
v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    CodeBase: 
 file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/
v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    CodeBase: 
 file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/
v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    CodeBase: 
file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/
v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    CodeBase: 
file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/
v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    CodeBase: 
file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/
v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I am using SQlite database and installed everything required. The project is runs well in visual studio. But when the setup file is built and run on my machine it throws this exception.

And I just don't understand what is this warning message.Should I turn on the Assembly binding logging? or whatsoever?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether your assembly '**SQLite.NET**' property **Copy Local** is true.

if yes you can also check

```
<dependentAssembly>  
    <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly"  
      publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
      culture="en-us" />  

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />  
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Replace your assembly name and version in upper configuration.

Comment: Where am I supposed to add this configuration?

Comment: `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="SQLite.NET"
          publicKeyToken="c273bd375e695f9c"
          culture="en-us" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.21.1869.3794" 
    newVersion="v1.1.4322" />
      </dependentAssembly>`
I have replaced it. But even then it doesn't work. the same error is shown again.

Comment: you need to add it in your configuration file under configuration->runtime->assemblyBinding